# SAP UI5 web IDE stroyboard builder. 403 error when trying to apply decending sorting

Tags: sapui5

I am currently building a simple web app in SAP web IDE using the storybaord editor. When I try to apply descending sorting to the data set the webbrowser reports the error:

The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed500,Internal Server Error,{ "error": { "code": "", "message": { "lang": "en-US", "value": "Service exception: [403] internal error"}}}

For example I am using the default sort method in the simplest applicaton possible (empty app with a list element), the sorter code is implemented as SAP details

```
            <List noDataText="Drop list items here" id="list0" items="{path:'/PerformanceStatistics',sorter:[{path:'END_TIME',descending:true}]}">
                <items>
                    <StandardListItem type="Navigation" title="{END_TIME}" description="Description text" icon="sap-icon://picture" id="item0"/>
                </items>
            </List>
```

I am stumped as why this would be failing, does anyone have any information on this specific issue or an alternative implementation of decending sort?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check, if your OData service supports sorting at all?

e.g. if you use the service GWSAMPLE_BASIC of the SAP ES5 test system
(https://sapes5.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/iwbep/GWSAMPLE_BASIC/$metadata) the properties are flagged 'sap:sortable="false"' resulting in a similar error as yours.